# Country flag not shown in chrome - Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, country-flag-icons

I have countries data like: code, name, region, emoji. The emoji is like '\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddfd'

ts:

```
public flagIcon = '\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddeb';
```

in html:

```
<p>{{flagIcon}}</p>
```

When I put this emoji in `<p>`, It looks good in Firefox. It's country flag image.

But in Chrome it's not shown as flag image.

What can I do for Chrome?

Comment: There's a polyfill to handle this: https://github.com/talkjs/country-flag-emoji-polyfill

Comment: Any help without npm install

Comment: The above package says it very clearly:

*Recent Windows versions (finally) support emojis natively, but they still do not support pretty country flags. By extension, all Chromium-based browsers can't display country flag emojis natively.*

*In short, if "" looks like "ᴄʜ" and not like a flag, then this polyfill is for you.*

So, there's no native support for flags yet.